# ssmtp myaddress@gmail.com < file.log doesn't work. Body is blank

Tags: rsync, echo, smtp, ssmtp, gmail

I'm running a simple `rsync` script where I log `stdout` and `stderr` to two different files, `rsync_stdout.log` and `rsync_stderr.log`.

When I'm trying to email the content of rsync_stderr.log using:

```
echo $(cat rsync_stderr.log) | ssmtp myaddress@gmail.com
```

I get a blank email body, but when I do:

```
echo $(cat rsync_stdout.log) | ssmtp myaddress@gmail.com
```

then I have my stdout log in the body of the email without problem.

Is it something to do with `rsync`'s `stderr` output file?

I ran ssmtp as verbose:

```
[<-] 250 2.1.5 OK b48smxxx70wrb.1 - gsmtp
[->] DATA
[<-] 354  Go ahead b48smxxxxxx70wrb.1 - gsmtp
[->] Received: by XXXNAS (sSMTP sendmail emulation); Tue, 19 Dec 2017 01:14:47 +0100
[->] From:"XXXNAS" <XXXNAS>>
[->] Date: Tue, 19 Dec 2017 01:14:47 +0100
[->] rsync: delete_file: unlink(.AppleDB/log.0000000001) failed: Permission denied (13)
[->] rsync: delete_file: unlink(.AppleDB/lock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[->] rsync: delete_file: unlink(.AppleDB/db_errlog) failed: Permission denied (13)
[->] rsync: delete_file: unlink(.AppleDB/cnid2.db) failed: Permission denied (13)
[->] rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1178) 
[->] [sender=3.1.2]
[->] 
[->] .
[<-] 250 2.0.0 OK 1513642487 b48sxxxxxxrb.1 - gsmtp
[->] QUIT
[<-] 221 2.0.0 closing connection b4xxxxxwrb.1 - gsmtp
```

So I can see the text being sent, but the email's body just comes blank.

I also tried `ssmtp myaddress@gmail.com < rsync_stderr.log` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you mean without the space between "<" and "file.log" ?

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed reading the very last line of the question where you said you already tried this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After user almendrico put me on the path, I used:

`sed 's/[\:]//g'` to remove the `:` character.

Not very elegant but works.